# How to fix stuck CUPS printer shared by remote

Tags: debian, cups, avahi, mdns

I have a server with two USB printers and multiple clients with Debian Bullseye. Clients are spread across LAN with same IP subnet and WLAN with a different subnet. The server shares both printer via CUPS *share this printer* option. The router reflects MDNS packets across these subnets.

A printer is detected on all clients as http://localhost:631/printers/Samsung_ML_2010_myserver (`myserver` being the server hostname)

Connection is displayed as: `implicitclass://Samsung_ML_2010_myserver/`

Printer is automatically going to status *Paused*. When I click *Resume printer* its status goes to *Idle - "No suitable destination host found by cups-browsed."*.

When trying to print the status goes to *Paused - "No destination host name supplied by cups-browsed for printer "Samsung_ML_2010_myserver", is cups-browsed running?"*

When I delete the printer locally it immediately appears again with status *Idle* but still doesn’t work. The only way I found so far to make the printer work again is to reboot the client.

I tried this to reset CUPS to a clean state but it doesn't help:

```bash
systemctl stop cups-browsed
systemctl stop cups

rm -fv /var/cache/cups/cups-browsed-options-*

systemctl start cups
systemctl start cups-browsed
```

1. How to restart/reset CUPS to make it correctly detect the "new" printer again? Having a workaround as a shell script would help a bit.
2. How to actually fix the problem of the printer becoming invalid?